# Android Market disappeared! How do I get it back?

Tags: google-play-store, 2.2-froyo, motorola-droid-x

Since upgrading to FroYo, the Android Market app has disappeared from my wife's Droid X: it doesn't appear on the home screen or in the Applications list in settings. Is there any way to get it back?

Comment: In what way has it "disappeared"? Do you mean it no longer appears as a shortcut icon on the home screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from here I tried  http://androidforums.com/droid-x-support-troubleshooting/196653-help-market-place-gone.html

To get the Marked app back, without doing a hard reset.

used ASTRO file manager

1. Opened ASTRO, clicked Up
2. navigate to /system/app
3. Locate Vending.apk
4. push on it to install it, clicked ok etc

Now back on home screen, follow what is suggested about a clean slate ...

1. Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications
2. Chose All
3. Find Market
4. Push on it and select Clear data
5. go back to main home screen, turn your phone off and back on

Comment: Worked great! I had to power cycle the phone before the Market would run though.

Answer (score 3):

<s>It's a built-in app and can't be uninstalled.</s>

To restore the icon to the home screen, find the icon in the application list and long-press, then drop it where you want it. Alternately, long-press the home screen where you want the icon to be, choose "Shortcuts", then "Applications", then the "Market" icon.

***Update***: Okay, it appears that you're not the only one with this issue. See this thread on the Google support forum: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android%20Market/thread?tid=3322620a3c715568&hl=en

One offered solution is to do a factory reset. It's up to you to decide how comfortable you are with that.

***Update 2***: Several people in [this thread](http://androidforums.com/droid-x-support-troubleshooting/196653-help-market-place-gone.html) said that the factory reset worked for them. Additionally, someone wrote a script (also in that thread) to fix the issue, which you would need to get on the phone. (USB would seem to be your best bet.) *Caveat Emptor*. Someone also mentioned that if you get the Vendor.apk you can also get the Market back. (Details are a little fuzzier.)

Comment: It really seems to be gone, as if the upgrade uninstalled it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running stock Android I believe you are going to have to do a factory reset.  If you are rooted and running some custom mod, you can probably just install the googleapps.apk or reflash the rom.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out, very easy.  The Android Market is now called "PLAY STORE" by Google, and is listed under "P" in your phone (not "G" for Google Play Store).  Just go into all your apps, go down to "P" and long hold the "PLAY STORE" icon to get it to your home screen.  This icon looks like a white shopping bag with handles and a blue, red and tan diamond/pyramid figure on the front.  GOOD LUCK and have a great day.

Comment: Please note: This question is from November, 2010. That the Market was just renamed to Google Play is obviously not the answer to this question.

Comment: @AlEverett This question will show up in Google searches for people who've just lost the Market icon due to the recent update. For that reason I think this is a valid answer?

Answer (score -1):

My android market icon dissapeared when i clicked on it yesterday on 2.2  i just read today in the news that google changed the name from Android market to Google Play to get more customers focused on its videos and books.  I found a brand new icon in the second apps location on my phone.  It is called google play not called  android market any longer. All you do is click accept and use.....

Comment: Note the date of the question.